# How to implement custom-built optimizer in Tensorflow/Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, runtime-error

I'm working on a research project and I have been provided a custom-made bio-optimizer (so the scholar says) that I need to train a model with on a SNN.

The bio-optimizer is as follows:

```
def __init__(self, epoch=10000, pop_size=100, somersault_range=2.0, \*\*kwargs):
"""
Args:
epoch (int): maximum number of iterations, default = 10000
pop_size (int): number of population size, default = 100
somersault_range (float): somersault factor that decides the somersault range of manta rays, default=2
"""
super().__init__(\*\*kwargs)
self.epoch = self.validator.check_int("epoch", epoch, \[1, 100000\])
self.pop_size = self.validator.check_int("pop_size", pop_size, \[10, 10000\])
self.somersault_range = self.validator.check_int("somersault_range", somersault_range, \[1.0, 5.0\])
self.set_parameters(\["epoch", "pop_size", "somersault_range"\])
self.nfe_per_epoch = 2 \* self.pop_size
self.sort_flag = False

    def evolve(self, epoch):
        """
        The main operations (equations) of algorithm. Inherit from Optimizer class
    
        Args:
            epoch (int): The current iteration
        """
        pop_new = []
        for idx in range(0, self.pop_size):
            # Cyclone foraging (Eq. 5, 6, 7)
            if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
                r1 = np.random.uniform()
                beta = 2 * np.exp(r1 * (self.epoch - epoch) / self.epoch) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * r1)
    
                if (epoch + 1) / self.epoch < np.random.rand():
                    x_rand = np.random.uniform(self.problem.lb, self.problem.ub)
                    if idx == 0:
                        x_t1 = x_rand + np.random.uniform() * (x_rand - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS]) + \
                               beta * (x_rand - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS])
                    else:
                        x_t1 = x_rand + np.random.uniform() * (self.pop[idx - 1][self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS]) + \
                               beta * (x_rand - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS])
                else:
                    if idx == 0:
                        x_t1 = self.g_best[self.ID_POS] + np.random.uniform() * (self.g_best[self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS]) + \
                               beta * (self.g_best[self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS])
                    else:
                        x_t1 = self.g_best[self.ID_POS] + np.random.uniform() * (self.pop[idx - 1][self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS]) + \
                               beta * (self.g_best[self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS])
            # Chain foraging (Eq. 1,2)
            else:
                r = np.random.uniform()
                alpha = 2 * r * np.sqrt(np.abs(np.log(r)))
                if idx == 0:
                    x_t1 = self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS] + r * (self.g_best[self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS]) + \
                           alpha * (self.g_best[self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS])
                else:
                    x_t1 = self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS] + r * (self.pop[idx - 1][self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS]) + \
                           alpha * (self.g_best[self.ID_POS] - self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS])
            pos_new = self.amend_position(x_t1, self.problem.lb, self.problem.ub)
            pop_new.append([pos_new, None])
            if self.mode not in self.AVAILABLE_MODES:
                target = self.get_target_wrapper(pos_new)
                self.pop[idx] = self.get_better_solution(self.pop[idx], [pos_new, target])
        if self.mode in self.AVAILABLE_MODES:
            pop_new = self.update_target_wrapper_population(pop_new)
            self.pop = self.greedy_selection_population(self.pop, pop_new)
        _, g_best = self.update_global_best_solution(self.pop, save=False)
        pop_child = []
        for idx in range(0, self.pop_size):
            # Somersault foraging   (Eq. 8)
            x_t1 = self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS] + self.somersault_range * \
                   (np.random.uniform() * g_best[self.ID_POS] - np.random.uniform() * self.pop[idx][self.ID_POS])
            pos_new = self.amend_position(x_t1, self.problem.lb, self.problem.ub)
            pop_child.append([pos_new, None])
            if self.mode not in self.AVAILABLE_MODES:
                target = self.get_target_wrapper(pos_new)
                self.pop[idx] = self.get_better_solution(self.pop[idx], [pos_new, target])
        if self.mode in self.AVAILABLE_MODES:
            pop_child = self.update_target_wrapper_population(pop_child)
            self.pop = self.greedy_selection_population(self.pop, pop_child)
```

And the SNN:

```
def snn(X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test):
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=X_train.shape\[1\], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    custom = IMRFO(epoch=10000, pop_size=100, somersault_range=2.0)
    
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=custom, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10000, batch_size=64, verbose=1)
    y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test), axis=1)
    return y_pred,confu_matrix(Y_test, y_pred)
```

Training code is as follows:

```
from objective_function import obj_fun
from MRFO import OriginalMRFO, IMRFO
from load_save import save, load
from BWO import OriginalBWO
from plot_res import plot_res
from classifier import \*
import numpy as np

X_train = load('X_train')
X_test = load('X_test')
y_train = load('y_train')
y_test = load('y_test')

def train_model(X_train, y_train, epoch, pop_size):

# Optimization parameters

lb = (np.zeros(\[1, X_train.shape\[1\]\]).astype('int16')).tolist()\[0\]
ub = (np.ones(\[1, X_train.shape\[1\]\]).astype('int16')).tolist()\[0\]
problem_dict1 = {"fit_func": obj_fun,
"lb": lb,
"ub": ub,
"minmax": "min"}

# Create IMRFO model

model = IMRFO(epoch, pop_size)

# Train the model

best_position, best_fitness = model.solve(problem_dict1)

return model

# Train the model

model = train_model(np.array(X_train), y_train, 10000, 100)

def predict(model, X_new):

# Make predictions

predictions = model.predict(X_new)

return predictions

# Make predictions on the test data

predictions = predict(model, X_test)
```

The code runs and executes one or two epochs and then shows optimizer error, which I think is because I'm using a custom defined optimizer and not Tensorflow optimizer:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.  
  model = train_model(np.array(X_train), y_train, 10000, 100)
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\train.py", line 33, in <module>
    model = train_model(np.array(X_train), y_train, 10000, 100)
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\train.py", line 28, in train_model
    best_position, best_fitness = model.solve(problem_dict1)
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\optimizer.py", line 262, in solve
    self.check_problem(problem)
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\optimizer.py", line 182, in check_problem
    self.problem = problem if isinstance(problem, Problem) else Problem(**problem)
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\utils\problem.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.__set_functions(kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\utils\problem.py", line 114, in __set_functions
    result = self.fit_func(tested_solution)
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\objective_function.py", line 15, in obj_fun
    pred, met = prop_classifier(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\classifier.py", line 160, in prop_classifier
    pred_feat_test[:,1],pred_feat_train[:,1]= snn(X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test)
  File "c:\Users\alosh\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCODE\DeepthyJ\classifier.py", line 72, in snn
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=custom, metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "C:\Users\alosh\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\alosh\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\__init__.py", line 230, in get
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: IMRFO(epoch=10000, pop_size=100, somersault_range=2)
```

How to implement the bio-optimizer as an inbuilt optimizer in future projects?

Comment: In order to code your own optimizer, I know two ways:
- if your optimizer is a gradient based your can try to fit [TF API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/core/optimizers_core)
- if your optimizer is a little more complicated, coding it entirely yourself might be an option as [Levenberg-Marquardt custom optimizer](https://github.com/fabiodimarco/tf-levenberg-marquardt/tree/main).